# Model Structure on Constant-free Symmetric Operads

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, operads

I am currently trying to find a reference for the assertion that the category of positive / constant-free (meaning $\cal{O}(0)=\emptyset$ is the initial object) symmetric operads $\operatorname{Opd}_\Sigma^+(\mathcal{M})$ in a reasonably well monoidal model category $\mathcal{M}$ admits a right-transferred model structure from the category of positive right symmetric sequences $\operatorname{Seq}_\Sigma^+(\mathcal{M})$.

The classical reference, Berger-Moerdijk's [Axiomatic Homotopy Theory for Operads](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206094.pdf), only discusses operads for which $\cal{O}(0)=\mathbb{1}$ is the monoidal unit of $\mathcal{M}$. According to Prof. White's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29636/operad-terminology-operads-with-and-without-o0) the result in question follows from results in Batanin-Berger's paper on [Homotopy Theory for Algebras over Polynomial Monads](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0086.pdf). While I am fine with having this abstract existence result, I would still like to know, whether anybody knows about an ad-hoc proof of the requested result written down somewhere.

Thank you for your time.